# Laravel Eloquent (A Model attribute won't show)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, attributes, undefined

I have a `Stat` Class :

```
class Stat extends Model
{
    public static function getByKey($key)
    {
        return Stat::where("key", "=", $key)->first();
    }

    public function getDates()
    {
        return json_decode($this->content);
    }
}
```

In my database the Table `stats` contains only two columns (key, content)
When I execute this function in my view an error occurs

```
{!! \App\Stat::getByKey("ORDERS-DATA")->getDates() !!}
```

and this makes this error :

```
Exception message: Undefined property: App\Stat::$content
```

So I added these two lines to the `getDates()` to debug the error :

```
public function getDates()
{
    dd($this->content);//This shows the same error
    dd($this->attributes["content"]);//This works fine and show me what I want
    return json_decode($this->content);
}
```

then I executed `dd($this)` and it shows this :

```
Stat {#486
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "stats"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:5 [
    "id" => 8
    "key" => "ORDERS-DATA"
    "content" => """
      [
      {
      \t"day": "2019-04-01",
      \t"count": "5"
      }
      ]
      """
    "created_at" => "2019-04-01 14:09:00"
    "updated_at" => "2019-04-01 14:11:02"
  ]
  #original: array:5 [
    "id" => 8
    "key" => "ORDERS-DATA"
    "content" => """
      [
      {
      \t"day": "2019-04-01",
      \t"count": "5"
      }
      ]
      """
    "created_at" => "2019-04-01 14:09:00"
    "updated_at" => "2019-04-01 14:11:02"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

And What I want is to get my `content` by `$this->content`, and I don't understand why it doesn't works ??
Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because I have overrided one of the Laravel functions.
the name `getDates` OR `getByKey` OR `getCounts` is used by Laravel.

> This is so weird this error happened to me two times in the same
>   day, Today's morning I created a function called `getAttributes()` and
>   showed me a total diferrent error. Why the community don't create a
>   list of functions names that we are not allowed to use, or use more
>   unique names ???